# SIunitx: S-Column alignment with confidence intervals

Tags: tables, siunitx

How do I correctly use the **s-column** of `SIunitx`-package, when I have results with **confidence intervals**, e. g. 22.34 +/- 0.37. I am using math mode `$\pm$`, utilizing the plus-minus symbol and I just wanna use one column for this purpose (I already had the idea of using two columns, one for the result and one for the confidence interval...). Currently, I am struggling  with the `table-format` option.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2~{$\pm$}~2.2]}
\toprule
Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\midrule
Raw 1   & 125.44~{$\pm$}~22.06 \\
Raw 2   & 300~{$\pm$}~50 \\
Raw 3   & 0.56~{$\pm$}~0.01 \\
Raw 4   & 31.59~{$\pm$}~0.29 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the correct format for uncertainties: no 'manual' formatting:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2(4),separate-uncertainty]}
\toprule
Column 1 & {Column 2} \\
\midrule
Raw 1   & 125.44\pm22.06 \\
Raw 2   & 300\pm50 \\
Raw 3   & 0.56\pm0.01 \\
Raw 4   & 31.59\pm0.29 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

How about using another column for the range?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=3.2]@{~$\pm$~}S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule
Column 1 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Column 2} \\
\midrule
Raw 1   & 125.44 & 22.06 \\
Raw 2   & 300    & 50    \\
Raw 3   & 0.56   & 0.01  \\
Raw 4   & 31.59  & 0.29  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]